# MySQL Workbench SSL connection error: SSL is required but the server doesn't support it

Tags: mysql, ssl, mysql-workbench

Greetings I'm trying to connect with MySQL Workbench to localhost on Ubuntu 21.10 and I get this error "SSL connection error: SSL is required but the server doesn't support it" how can I fix it?

[image: mysql-workbench]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This answer helped me in Workbench 8.0
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/303329

Basically, create new connection using the advanced tab by entering "useSSL=0" in the 'Others' tab.

[image: Advanced tab, then Others field]

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Comment: No need create a new connection just edit the existing connection by adding "useSSL = 0 "on the others section in advanced Tab

Comment: Thanks, @Aldrin Jenson for orientation. Just adding one more step. Doing this step From Manage Connection not keeping the useSSL=0 to stay while connecting to DB. 
I needed to do the same steps from "Connect To Database... Ctrl+U" Option.

Although each time I do so, It does not throw any error, and Workbench shutdown improperly.

Comment: Also, we need to download Workbench version 8.0.26 to have "No" and "If Available" in SSL tab so that SSL is not Required while connecting as mentioned by @Bleuuu in one of the answer. Can be downloaded from - https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can set "useSSL=0" in the 'Others' tab, but unfortunately when switch to another tab of MySQLWorkbench and then switch back, that setting is just disappeared... At least for me in version 8.0.27, on MacOS. And then sometimes later that annoying prompt is showing again, don't know why...

TO SOLVE this question once and for all, you better downgrade it to version 8.0.26 at this place: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/, and the   SSL options are all back, so you don't need to use "useSSL=0".

Answer (score 4):

one way to fix this is to go to `/usr/share/mysql-workbench/modules/data/` and open the file `mysql_rdbms_info.xml` (in some cases there are two files with this name, but none of these exist you will find the following text).

Once inside the file, we will look for "2 | Require, 3 | Require and verify CA, 4 | Require and verify identity" and add "0 | No, 1 | If available" to the lines that do not contain this. Save the changes and then yes, follow these steps:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69828778

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following steps:

1. Open MySQL workbench
2. right-click on the particular MySQL instance and select "**Edit Connection**"
3. Select the "**SSL**" tab under **Connection Method**
4. Select the drop-down for the "**Use SSL**" and choose "**If Available**" instead of "**Required**".
5. Click the "*Test Connection*" button at the lower right connection to make sure you can now connect without errors.

You need to downgrade to a lower workbench version [here](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/) in order to see more options in the drop-down from step 4.

Comment: The problem is because it's doesn't say If Available [link](https://imgur.com/nYHdec0)

Comment: Same problem. doesnt say if available...

Comment: @StefanMomcilovic, you will have to downgrade: https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/

Comment: It doesn't have a option call if available

Comment: @HasithaPriyasadWijerathna, downgrade to a lower version using this link https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/ inorder to see the "If available" option.